# Open another one application from our application?

Tags: android

From my application i have to open a another one application.Is there any possibility to open like this?

Comment: check the use of Intents http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 8):

You should use the function of the package manager.

```
try {
    Intent i = ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.browser");
    ctx.startActivity(i);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: In case getLaunchIntentForPackage returns null, please, refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65140578/1803222 or this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring. In short, you must add 
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.store" />
</queries>
 to your manifest.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are looking for a way to start another class from another package

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("com.android.samples", "com.android.samples.Animation1");
myIntent.putExtra("com.android.samples.SpecialValue", "Hello, Joe!"); // key/value pair, where key needs current package prefix.
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Read a tutorial post about [Opening a Screen](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html) at Common Tasks post.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch other applications with Activity.startActivity( intent);

Use it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String pkg = "com.android.browser";
String cls = "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity";
intent.setClassName(pkg, cls); 
startActivity(intent);
```

You need to know the package and class names of the activity to call, the Package Browser in the Dev Tools app will help here if its not your own app to call.

Comment: Please note that using hand-written constants like "com.android.browser" and "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity" is using private implementation details (these are not part of the SDK), and thus you should expect such code to break across different devices and platform versions.