# EditText - endbling user to select part of text so that selection stays on EditText's text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, selection

I got a problem that seem to be unsolveable.
EditText has longclick selection of text, but by longpressing it I got some sort of control panel which hides my Action Bar. And I don't need that control panel. I want a user to select some text and then be able to Share it with ShareProvider to e-mail,Facebook or whatever.

But this "control panel" spoils it - I don't need it, I can't reach Action Bar because of it and - if I press comething like "copy" - selection goes off, and I need it to stay!
I need the user to have opportunity to select come text, not copying it to clipboard, just select, and Share it with ShareProvider.

Comment: u mean select a text from a bunch of text and share it?

Comment: i saw this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281489/how-to-fire-an-event-like-launch-an-application-when-a-text-is-selected