# How to open android application if exists

Tags: android

I would like to make android button and able to launch other application if already installed and go to S specified url  if not yet installed.

Comment: Can you please explain your question properly? A bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=your.example.namespace.CUSTOMACTION;package=your.example.namespace;component=your.example.namespace/.activity.YourActivity;S.extraValueName=WOW;end">
Launch App
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

OR

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.name","com.package.name.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call specific application if you know the package name.

[How do I programmatically launch a specific application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343432/how-do-i-programmatically-launch-a-specific-application-in-android)