# Android tablet app remote launch

Tags: android, adb, remote-access, tablet, monkeyrunner

I need to use the android based tablet for a specific functionality of starting the tablet remotely (without pushing any physical button), then launching a specific app. The functionality is as below.

After android tablet boots up, a specific video player starts and plays a specific video file.

I have found a program called Looper which plays any video file in a loop. But I do not know how to start the tablet remotely (if its possible at all), and let it launch this looper program to play a file in loop. If there is any other loop program that can play a specific file its good too.

I have come across tools like adb, monkeyrunner, but I think for both of them the tablet has to be connected to a PC. Whereas what I possibly want is remotely controlling the tablet, may be from a phone app or something.

If remote starting is not possible, is it possible that after manually starting the tablet, a specific app could be always launched without navigating in app collection and manually launching it. (like in this case the video player in a looper program). I came across this,

[How do I programmatically launch a specific application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343432/how-do-i-programmatically-launch-a-specific-application-in-android)  are there more alternatives possibly?

Any help and pointers are extremely appreciated.

Thanks
Mrunal

Comment: As i know this is impossible ...

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? I have done my basic homework of trying to find alternatives and hence I am asking this question here. If I would find an answer I won't ask it here in the first place.

Comment: Ok So I found this ready made app that allows starting of a dedicated app after android bootup. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autostart&hl=en

Comment: Have you tried an **IP Power Switch** possibly removing the tablet battery ?

Comment: No, I have not. thanks for the suggestion, I will see how to do that. But I do not think I can remove tablet battery that easily, because it seems an integrated case without openings possibility

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I managed to get this working at least partially using the following workflow.

1. First, make the video player default for video files (I used mxplayer as it allows to loop a single video on android unlike VLC).
2. Then, use Tasker app and create a task to Open File on boot. Open File action can be found in File action category.
3. Then create a profile and add Event -> system -> Device Boot - > and link the above Open File Video task to this profile context
4. Then in the Android Settings - > Security - > auto-start management add the tasker app.
5. This workflow lets you play a video in a loop manner after starting your android tablet after it boots up without any manual intervention