# Launch an application within another one

Tags: android, ios

Is it possible to launch an application within another application in Android and iOS. Something like this.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about android, but i'm pretty sure this is not possible with iOS.

Comment: use heritage in interface

Comment: There might be a potential way to programmatically enter split-screen mode with the second app that you would desire to launch with your own if that is something that would be helpful for you (but you would have to research that its just a thought).  There are built in ways to call certain common apps from without our own, like gallery pickers and media servers to accomplish tasks via a general type of intent.  If either of those work for you, then research the approach and see if it will solve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In Android - No, every app in Android runs in its own "sandbox". Only one thing you can is start another app via `intent` if you know the package name of the app like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262904/4001920). But the app will be started separatelly.